# Get frame rates list and pixel format from capture device? (WPF MediaKit)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-mediakit

1. I can get a list of resolutions supported by the capture device (from `VideoInfoHeader` and `BmiHeader`). But I can not figure out **how to get a list of frame rates**.
2. Similarly, I'm looking for **how to set a pixel format** (for example `uyvy422`).

Is it possible to set this up using [WPF-MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)?

**Edit:**
I found that the pixel format I need is `MediaSubType.UYVY` (corresponding to `uyvy422`). But so far I do not know how to set it for the capture device.

Comment: Not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659826/how-to-change-fps-size-in-wpfmediakit) might help

Comment: @zackraiyan Thanks a lot, helped me find [YUV Video Subtypes > MEDIASUBTYPE_UYVY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391027(v=vs.85).aspx), but I do not know how to set it in WPF-MadiaKit. Can it somehow through AMMediaType?

Comment: i am a bit busy now but i'll try to post an answer later,hope that's ok for u :)

Comment: @zackraiyan Please do not forget me with the answer ;-)

Comment: i am sorry...i almost forgot... :)

Comment: @zackraiyan I understand you do not have time :) Should you please at least some similar code that would help me understand how to set MediaSubType.UYVY into the capture device?

Comment: i am sorry , i tried to figure this out but failed......sorry to keep u waiting :( .. I'll try my best to help u in future